# pass method value to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

i have a method in my Component `IncomeList`, which contains the method `sumValue`. This method just added different numbers together and output one value, like 3+5 = 8. Same in my other Component `OutputList`, the same logic is used but the method is called `sumValueOutput`. Now i want to use both values in another component, which is called `WinTotal`. I tried something with props and vuex, but till now i have no working product and i also dont know how to start. Thanks for helping!

IncomeList:

```
<template>
<div class="container-income">
    <button class="btn btn-info" @click="showModal">show modal</button>
    <div class="hidden-container-income" id="test123">
    <input type="text" class="income-input" placeholder="What needs to be done" v-model="newIncome" @keyup.enter="addincome">
    <input type="text" class="value-input" placeholder="€" v-model="newIncomeValue" @keyup.enter="addValue">
    <transition-group name="fade" enter-active-class="animated fadeInUp" leave-active-class="animated fadeOutDown">
        <income-item v-for="income in incomesFiltered" :key="income.id" :income="income"
                   @removedIncome="removeincome">
        </income-item>
    </transition-group>

    <div class="extra-container">
        <div><label><input type="checkbox" style="display: none" :checked="!anyRemaining" @change="checkAllincomes"></label></div>
        <div>{{ remaining }} elements</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sum-container">
        <div><label> Total Income: </label></div>
        <div>{{ sumValue }} €</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import IncomeItem from './IncomeItem'
    export default {
    name: 'income-list',
    components: {
        IncomeItem,
    },
    data () {
        return {
            newIncome: '',
            newIncomeValue: '',
            idForincome: 3,
            incomes: [
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'title': 'Finish Vue Screencast',
                    'value': 300,
                    'completed': false,
                    'editing': false,
                },
                {
                    'id': 2,
                    'title': 'Take over world',
                    'value': 315,
                    'completed': false,
                    'editing': false,
                },
                {
                    'id': 3,
                    'title': 'Excellent',
                    'value': 313,
                    'completed': false,
                    'editing': false,
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        remaining() {
            return this.incomes.filter(income => !income.completed).length
        },
        anyRemaining() {
            return this.remaining != 0
        },
        incomesFiltered() {
            return this.incomes
        },
        sumValue() {
            return this.incomesFiltered.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value, 0)
        },
    },
    methods: {
            addincome() {
                if (this.newIncome.trim().length == 0) {
                    return
                }
                this.incomes.push({
                    id: this.idForincome,
                    title: this.newIncome,
                    value: this.newIncomeValue,
                    completed: false,
                })
                this.newIncome = ''
                this.newIncomeValue = ''
                this.this.idForincome++
            },

        removeincome(id) {
            const index = this.incomes.findIndex((item) => item.id == id)
            this.incomes.splice(index, 1)
        },
        checkAllincomes() {
            this.incomes.forEach((income) => income.completed = event.target.checked)
        },
        clearCompleted() {
            this.incomes = this.incomes.filter(income => !income.completed)
        },
        finishedEdit(data) {
            const index = this.incomes.findIndex((item) => item.id == data.id)
            this.incomes.splice(index, 1, data)
        },
        //Same for Value
        addValue() {
            if (this.newIncomeValue.trim().length == 0) {
                return
            }
            this.incomes.push({
                id: this.idForincome,
                title: this.newIncome,
                value: this.newIncomeValue,
                completed: false,
            })
            this.newIncome = ''
            this.newIncomeValue = ''
            this.this.idForincome++
        },
        showModal () {
            if (document.getElementById('test123').style.display == 'none' ) {
                document.getElementById('test123').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                
                
document.getElementById('test123').style.display = 'none'
            }
        },
    },
};
                               </script>
```

OutputList:

```
<template>
<div class="container-output1">
    <button class="btn btn-info1" @click="showModal">show modal</button>
    <div class="hidden-container-output1" id="test1231">
        <input type="text" class="output-input1" placeholder="What needs to be done" v-model="newOutput" @keyup.enter="addoutput">
        <input type="text" class="value-input1" placeholder="€" v-model="newOutputValue" @keyup.enter="addValue">
        <transition-group name="fade" enter-active-class="animated fadeInUp" leave-active-class="animated fadeOutDown">
            <output-item v-for="output in outputsFiltered" :key="output.id" :output="output"
                         @removedoutput="removeOutput">
            </output-item>
        </transition-group>

        <div class="extra-container1">
            <div><label><input type="checkbox" style="display: none" :checked="!anyRemaining" @change="checkAlloutputs"></label></div>
            <div>{{ remaining }} elements</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sum-container1">
            <div><label> Total Output: </label></div>
            <div>{{ sumValueOutput }} €</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </template>

   <script>
import OutputItem from './OutputItem'
export default {
    name: 'output-list',
    components: {
        OutputItem,
    },
    data () {
        return {
            newOutput: '',
            newOutputValue: '',
            idForOutput: 3,
            outputs: [
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'title': 'Finish Vue Screencast',
                    'value': 300,
                    'completed': false,
                    'editing': false,
                },
                {
                    'id': 2,
                    'title': 'Take over world',
                    'value': 315,
                    'completed': false,
                    'editing': false,
                },
                {
                    'id': 3,
                    'title': 'Excellent',
                    'value': 311,
                    'completed': false,
                    'editing': false,
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        remaining() {
            return this.outputs.filter(output => !output.completed).length
        },
        anyRemaining() {
            return this.remaining != 0
        },
        outputsFiltered() {
            return this.outputs
        },
        sumValueOutput() {
            var outputValue = this.outputsFiltered.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value, 0);
            return outputValue;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        addOutput() {
            if (this.newOutput.trim().length == 0) {
                return
            }
            this.outputs.push({
                id: this.idForOutput,
                title: this.newOutput,
                value: this.newOutputValue,
                completed: false,
            })
            this.newOutput = ''
            this.newOutputValue = ''
            this.this.idForOutput++
        },

        removeOutput(id) {
            const index = this.outputs.findIndex((item) => item.id == id)
            this.outputs.splice(index, 1)
        },
        checkAlloutputs() {
            this.outputs.forEach((output) => output.completed = event.target.checked)
        },
        clearCompleted() {
            this.outputs = this.outputs.filter(output => !output.completed)
        },
        finishedEdit(data) {
            const index = this.outputs.findIndex((item) => item.id == data.id)
            this.outputs.splice(index, 1, data)
        },
        //Same for Value
        addValue() {
            if (this.newOutputValue.trim().length == 0) {
                return
            }
            this.outputs.push({
                id: this.idForOutput,
                title: this.newOutput,
                value: this.newOutputValue,
                completed: false,
            })
            this.newOutput = ''
            this.newOutputValue = ''
            this.this.idForOutput++
        },
        showModal () {
            if (document.getElementById('test1231').style.display == 'none' ) {
                document.getElementById('test1231').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('test1231').style.display = 'none'
            }
        }

    }
}
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of immediately that should work for you:

### 1) Pass data using a Bus

In Vue you can pass data between a child component and its parent fairly easily. In the child component you [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) the data you want to send, as an event:

```js
this.$emit('event-name', payload)
```

...and, in the parent, you listen for the event, and do something with the data:

```html
<child-component @event-name="doSomething($event)" />
```

But passing data between two components becomes trickier. You can pass data from a component to component through a child-parent-child strategy, but that becomes tedious. Instead, what you can do is create a [Bus](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus): an instance of Vue which you import in both child components and emit events directly between the two.

A Bus is easy to make; requiring all but two lines of code:

```js
// Bus.js
import Vue from "vue";

export const Bus = new Vue();
```

So in your child component(s), (`IncomeList` and `OutputList`) you import the Bus:

```js
import { Bus } from "@/Bus";
```

...and emit an event with the value of `sumValue` (in `IncomeList`)

```js
sumValue() {
    const sumVal = this.incomesFiltered.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value, 0);
    Bus.$emit("sumvalue-change", sumVal);
    return sumVal;
}
```

...and `sumOutputValue` (in `OutputList`):

```js
sumValueOutput() {
    const outputValue = this.outputsFiltered.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value, 0);
    Bus.$emit("sumvalueoutput-change", outputValue);
    return outputValue;
}
```

Then in `WinTotal.vue`, you import the Bus and listen for these events, in the component's `created` hook:

```js
created() {
    Bus.$on("sumvalue-change", (sumvalue) => (this.sumValue = sumvalue));
    Bus.$on("sumvalueoutput-change", (sumvalueoutput) => (this.sumValueOutput = sumvalueoutput));
}
```

You can now use the `sumValue` and `sumValueOutput` in `WinTotal` however you want, and they'll be automatically updated whenever they change in either `IncomeList` or `OutputList`.

[image: emit-demo-working]

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-method-value-to-another-component-with-a-bus-t83xu?file=/src/App.vue) demonstrating this solution.

**HOWEVER**, there's a downside to this method. Say your `App.vue` looks like this:

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <IncomeList />
    <OutputList />
    <WinTotal />
  </div>
</template>
```

In this case both `IncomeList` and `OutputList` are rendered *before* `WinTotal`, so the initial values of `sumValue` and `sumValueOutput` are emitted *before* `WinTotal` has even begun listening for these events. Thus, `WinTotal` never receives the initial values of `sumValue` and `sumValueOutput` (see below).

[image: emit-demo-broken]

As you can see, `WinTotal` isn't updated initially with the values, but when they change, they are updated fine. A workaround is to put `<WinTotal />` before `<IncomeList />` and `<OutputList />`, but that's not always feasible. Sure you could get around this in other ways, but it'd likely be tedious to implement, and not worth the trouble. So, here's an alternative.

### 2) Passing data using VueX

A simpler solution would be to just use VueX. I'm assuming you know a bit about VueX already, since you've mentioned that you've tried something with it previously, but if there's anything unclear, let me know.

Assuming VueX is set up already, in your [`store`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#vuex-store), create values in [`state`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#single-state-tree) for `sumValueIncome` and `sumValueOutput`, and [`mutations`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) that update them:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    sumValueIncome: null,
    sumValueOutput: null
  },
  mutations: {
    updatesumValueIncome(state, newvalue) {
      state.sumValueIncome = newvalue;
    },
    updatesumValueOutput(state, newvalue) {
      state.sumValueOutput = newvalue;
    }
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

Then in `IncomeList`, you update `sumValueIncome` like in the previous solution (but with `VueX`, of course):

```js
sumValueIncome() {
  const sumValueIncome = this.incomesFiltered.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value, 0);
  this.$store.commit("updatesumValueIncome", sumValueIncome);
  return sumValueIncome;
}
```

...and in `OutputList`:

```js
sumValueOutput() {
  const outputValue = this.outputsFiltered.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value, 0);
  this.$store.commit("updatesumValueOutput", outputValue);
  return outputValue;
}
```

In `WinTotal`, you can use the [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) helper to create computed properties with the dynamically updated values of `sumValue` and `sumValueOutput`:

```html
<template>...</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "win-total",
  computed: mapState(["sumValueIncome", "sumValueOutput"]),
};
</script>
```

...and you're all set!

[image: vuex-demo]

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-method-value-to-another-component-with-vuex-cq8pq?file=/src/App.vue) demonstrating this solution.

---

Comment: Instead of using a Vue instance as Bus you should use Vue.observable() since v2.6 or, in Vue 3 just use `reactive`. Or you could use any vue-bus plugin. Most of them come with helper methods, such as `$once`.